# Nested form in Rails. Can't create and associate a parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested, fields-for

So basically I tried to create a record in a parent model for few hours. I'm clearly missing something here. My goal is to create a bill in the Bills table and, with basic guest info in the same form, create another record in the Guests table. View my code down below (sorry if the format is not adequate, it's my first post on stackoverflow)

#### bill.rb

```
class Bill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :guest, inverse_of: :bills
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :guest
```

#### guest.rb

```
class Guest < ApplicationRecord    
  has_many :bills, inverse_of: :guest
```

#### bills_controller.rb

```
def new
    @bill = Bill.new
    @bill.build_guest

...

def create
  @bill = Bill.new(bill_params)

if @bill.save

...

def bill_params
    params.require(:bill).permit(:special_req, guest_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email])
```

#### _form.html.haml

```
=form_with(model: [:admin, @bill], local: true) do |form| 
    .form-group.row
        .col-3
            = form.label :room_id, class: "col-form-label text-dark"
        .col-9
            = form.collection_select :room_id, @availabilities, :id, :door_no, class: "col-form-label text-dark"
    = form.fields_for :guests do |guest_form|
        .form-group.row
            .col-3
                = guest_form.label :first_name, class: "col-form-label text-dark"
            .col-9
                = guest_form.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control rounded", placeholder: "Tom"
        .form-group.row
            .col-3
                = guest_form.label :last_name, class: "col-form-label text-dark"
            .col-9
                = guest_form.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control rounded", placeholder: "Jedusor"
        .form-group.row.margin-bottom
            .col-3
                = guest_form.label :email, class: "col-form-label text-dark"
            .col-9
                = guest_form.text_field :email, class: "form-control rounded", placeholder: "nagano@inn.com"
    .form-group.row.align-items-center
        .col-6
            = link_to "[ Cancel operation ]", admin_bills_path, class: "text-info"
        .col-6.text-right
            = form.submit "Send", class: "btn btn-outline-success btn-lg"
```

A guest can have multiple bills, but a bill can only have one guest. Account registration is not a question for now, it's just there to serve some record purposes. This is just an exercise, so there is no real world deployment. Still, I need to go through that step.

Comment: can you post the console log during the form submission? It'll help to understand what data are passing. 
For now, only problem I see is missing `:id` inside strong parameters for `guests_attributes`. like: `guest_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email, :id]`

Comment: Its a simple pluralization error - it should read `form.fields_for :guest` - not `:guests`.

Comment: I completely forgot to check the console. Max was right and, now, it works! I won't forget to post the log next time.

Answer (score 0):

The form view using `form.fields_for :guests do |guest_form|` looks correct.

Pretty sure you need to add `:id` in `guest_attributes: [:first_name, :last_name, :email]`

For Example:

```
params.require(:bill).permit(:special_req, guest_attributes: [:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email])
```

Comment: This is not correct. The pluralization should match the association which is `belongs_to  :guest`.  Not whitelisting the id will cause it to create new nested records instead of updating existing records but that's not really the issue here.

Comment: You are right, Max. The pluralization was my issue. Rails creates records without the id. Not gonna lie, I was tired and started to add weird stuff everywhere. Thanks for your contribution! :)